# How to display customized page URL?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewrite-module

Let me explain with example:

Whenever someone opens account on my website, he/she will also create one store ID like `MyHawaiiSpa`. Once store ID will be generated then it can not be changed. Here I have assumed `pkid` of this account is 1.

Now, visitor clicks `MyHawaiiSpa` store link from home page, visitor will be sent to `shop.php` where all items belong to `MyHawaiiSpa` will be displayed. And by clicking on any product on `MyHawaiiSpa` store will open `product.php` page where product detail is mentioned.

Currently I have managed it using query string in PHP. so each store are distinguished like this:

```
mywebsite.com/user/shop.php?sid=1
```

---

Depending on internet study, I tried following things but it's not working.

I want to get result as I mentioned here:

```
www.mywebsite.com/user/shop.php?mid=1&sid="MyHawaiiSpa"
```

OR

```
www.mywebsite.com/user/shop.php?sid="MyHawaiiSpa"
```

TO

```
www.mywebsite.com/user/MyHawaiiSpa
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Product Details 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^user/(.+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="user/shop.php?sid={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: have you tried to use `mod_rewrite` to redirect the links ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my final code which is working now.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>  
            <rules>  
                <rule name="QueryStringDynamicRewrite" stopProcessing="true">  
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />  
                        <conditions>  
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />  
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(admin|mdm|user/includes)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>  
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="user/shop.php?sid={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />  
                </rule>
            </rules>  
        </rewrite> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Important things for IIS 7 or above Web Server, Web.Config, PHP, MySQL combination.

- Previously I used "^user/(.+)$ that now I have replaced with "^user/(.*)$". (+ symbol is replaced with *).
- I confirmed with my web hosting server provider GoDaddy and they said that we should use Web.Config with IIS.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is not if you are using  `IIS`  or any `OS` , your request can be done by `htaccess` `mod_rewrite`

1- check your php info if mod_rewrite extension is enabled by adding `phpinfo()` in test page

2- create file `.htaccess` and put this file in your script root

3- add this ruls inside `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$  shop.php?sid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*)$ user/shop.php?mid=$2&sid=$1   [L,NC,QSA]
```

now you can use this link

```
www.mywebsite.com/user/MyHawaiiSpa
```

or

```
www.mywebsite.com/user/MyHawaiiSpa/1
```

add this rule just to make sure if you are doing well

1- create test.php page and add it in the root folder

add this line to `.htaccess` file below `RewriteBase /`

```
RewriteRule ^test test.php [L,NC]
```

now access the page

```
www.mywebsite.com/test
```

if still not working u need to enable and install mod_rewrite in php , you can google it how to

Comment: No there is no mod_rewrite extension in phpinfo() test page. I only found this variable - SERVER["IIS_UrlRewriteModule"] and it's value is 7.1.0761.0

Comment: Hello, It's giving this error. Not Found. The requested document was not found on this server. I put .htaccess under user folder as well as root folder to check but in both cases, it's not working.

Comment: www.mywebsite.com/test, it's not giving error but asking for username / password. Please let me know.

Comment: I think I am trying to access root of website that's why it's asking for username/password

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess. It can be used for rewritting URLs.

Comment: But I am using IIS with Windows 7.